# Can FitNesse page tags be used in page?

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Is there a way in FitNesse to access page tags from inside the page?

I need to change database connection strings at test start-up and would like to use a tag as a switch.

Comment: I don't think you can access the tags on a page. But... How exactly do you intend to use the the tag? A tag would always be the same for all tests, wouldn't it? Have you considered the use of markup variables (http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupVariables), maybe combined with symbolic links? That would my first idea to parameterise something like a connection string.

Comment: @FriedHoeben My intention was that I could use a tag's value during the setup phase of a test as a switch variable for an action which will configure the databse for the system under test. This way I could set which database (i.g. local or azure) is to be used.

As a work-around I am currently using the test page's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you create multiple top level suites, one for each environment (e.g. one for testing locally and one for Azure) that defines the environment specific settings using wiki symbols (i.e. `!define ...`). The tests that are to be executed in all environments can be defined is separate suite that is included in each environment's suite using a [symbolic link](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.SymbolicLinks). The tests in the shared suites use the wiki symbols to get the values for the environment they are included in.

- This makes it explicit which settings are different between each environment
- All different environments are visible in the wiki
- Adding or removing an environment setting requires no (fixture) code changes
- You can add environment specific tests for each environment (just add them to the environment's suite besides the shared tests included via symbolic link)